# Which Language Should I Use To Make An App To Calculate My Payment?

Tags: timer, payment

I'm paid by the hour and I want to make an app which I will start at the beginning of 
my shift and the features I want to include are:

- Timer
- Time Of Shift Start And End
- Date Of Shift
- Ability To Save A Full History Of When And For How Much I Worked

etc.

Maybe C? But will I be able to make a GUI relatively easily? BASIC is not a viable option... And I am obviously a rookie so please be mercifull...

I am using Notepad++

The capitals are a problem i have yet to surpass.

Isn't VB.Net A Kind Of Basic?

Comment: You should be paid by the upper-case letter, you'd earn more money that way. ohWell. atLeastYouDidntUseCamelCase.

Comment: This sounds subjective and not a real question.. voting to close...depending on your skillsets, how about VB.NET for a rookie?!

Comment: The question was edited for readability, if you're wondering what paxdiablo was talking about.

Comment: Yes, Every Single Word Originally Started With A Capital Letter, Which Makes @darma's Comment Pretty Damn Funny :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't have a lot of programming experience, you might want to set up a simple Microsoft Excel spreadsheet.  Set up columns for `Date`, `Start Time`, `End Time`, a calculated column to display the `End-Start Time` and a running total of hours worked.  You could even add a formula to multiply the hours worked by your wage to see what you have made.

If you want to do more, you can use VBA to extend any simple solution.

Answer (score 0):

Use the programming language that you are most familiar/experienced with. You'll certainly do a much better job with a language you know well than with a language you've learned in a few days.